# Git merge: conflict I don't know how to resolve

Tags: python, django, git

I have a Django project on Git

I am not very confortable with Git

I have juste finalized, commit and push my feature/22 branch

I have commit (after git add .) and push my master

So my two branchs are up to date

Now, I would like to merge my master with my feature/22 locally but I have an conflict

Even after commit, I have 2 files in "Unmerge paths" :

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both modified:   unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0002_auto_20200124_0904.cpython-37.pyc
        both modified:   unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0003_auto_20200124_1007.cpython-37.pyc
```

What if I use the recommanded command git add?

Why these 2 files were not contained in the previous git add . command?

**EDIT:**

```
$ git merge feature/22
warning: Cannot merge binary files: unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0003_auto_20200124_1007.cpython-37.pyc (HEAD vs. feature/22)
warning: Cannot merge binary files: unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0002_auto_20200124_0904.cpython-37.pyc (HEAD vs. feature/22)
Auto-merging unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0003_auto_20200124_1007.cpython-37.pyc
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0003_auto_20200124_1007.cpython-37.pyc
Auto-merging unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0002_auto_20200124_0904.cpython-37.pyc
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in unblind/migrations/__pycache__/0002_auto_20200124_0904.cpython-37.pyc
Removing randomization/templates/randomization/_randomisation_edit.html
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

**EDIT2:**

I have resolved temporarly my merge problem:

- git checkout feature/22
- rm  (all files that were mentionned in CONFLICT when merge master / feature/22
- git commit -m "delete *.pyc"
- git checkout master
- git merge feature/22
- git push origin master

BUT .pyc are still tracked and after running my django project on master, if I do git status:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   export/migrations/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   parameters/migrations/__pycache__/0003_auto_20200128_1337.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   parameters/migrations/__pycache__/0004_auto_20200129_1206.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   parameters/migrations/__pycache__/0005_auto_20200305_0810.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   parameters/migrations/__pycache__/0006_auto_20200305_1238.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   parameters/migrations/__pycache__/0007_auto_20200305_1242.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   parameters/migrations/__pycache__/0008_auto_20200305_1428.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0002_auto_20200129_1206.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0003_auto_20200129_1434.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0004_auto_20200210_1750.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0005_historicalstock_stock.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0006_auto_20200218_1344.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0007_auto_20200218_1359.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0008_auto_20200218_1403.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0009_auto_20200218_1410.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/0010_auto_20200302_1059.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   pharmacy/migrations/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   randomization/migrations/__pycache__/0008_auto_20200302_1059.cpython-37.pyc

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        unblind/migrations/__pycache__/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/django

Answer (score 6):

You can ignore any `/__pycache__/` folder from your project.

1. If you don't already have a `.gitignore`, you can make one right inside of your project folder: `project/.gitignore`.
2. Put `*/__pycache__/*` in the `.gitignore`

Comment: I have updated my gitignore in master a feature/22 but still have conflict (see EDIT for more detail)

Comment: can I simply delete these files?

Comment: @SLATER Yes. Python will create them again itself. So try `git rm -r unblind/migrations/__pycache__/`

Answer (score 2):

remove those cached file with

```
rm -rf <path_of_filename>
```

try not to push your code with

```
 git add.
```

keep practice to start adding

> .gitignore

before starting of any project, and add cache,compiled files into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is never a good idea to store your pycache files in your git repository.
This files are automatically generated by the  [py_compile module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html) on each build.

You can add this files to resolve the merge conflict, but I recommend to use a .gitignore at root of your project.

Here is a good [.gitignore](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore) to add in your project.

Comment: my gitigonre start with ```# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class
*/__pycache__/*``` but even with this I've had this problem...

Comment: As theses files will be regenerated when code will be compiled, can I delete them without side effect?

Comment: What is the output of git status ? If you have this *.pyc files in the output, that's mean your .gitignore is not applied. Resolve your conflicts by opening each file causing errors and save as you want. Then delete all *.pyc and rebuild your project.

Comment: you should be rigth but don't know why my gitignore is not applied...

Comment: I have read it may be a problem of encoding (?) or because I created my gitigore after git init so all files were already tracked... and that is possible... how can I resolve that?

Comment: I also try git rm -r --cached .

Comment: then git add . to add tracked files and those mentionned in my gitignore should not be tracked)

Comment: and git commit -m "fix .gitignore"

Comment: No, it's not ignored. These files have already been indexed by git - how can it stop taking care about them? You need to clear your git history of these files before git starts ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. It was resolved by putting  < */**pycache**/* > in the .gitignore file and than re-committing the changes.